# What are the good resources for learning Metasploit?

Tags: metasploit

I'm a newbie (Script kiddie) and I want to learn more about Metasploit. Not for fun, but to understand what exploits are, how they are used, and deployed. I've heard a lot about the Metasploit framework being good. I've even started reading [the Offensive Security with Metasploit tutorials](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Main_Page) but I'm finding it somewhat hard to follow, as they've introduced a lot of new jargon. Also, I'm more used to coding stuff and I learn more by interacting. So, I'd like to do more like a "Hello World" sort of thing. However I didn't find any such resources. Can anyone provide me with any resources/links?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing is that metasploit infact is a framework, so a collection of exploits. The beautiful thing about a framework is that you don't *need* to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

I think that if you want to learn more about exploits and how they work, you pick yourself up some basic books like [The Shellcoder's Handbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047008023X). If you want a more hands-on experience, it's better to start with easy exploiting challenges. Check out http://smashthestack.org/. They have different challenges that start really easy and steadily increase in complexity. You can then apply what you read in the previous named book. If you find yourself in a pickle, there should be ample information on the net.